# Eclipse: Selectively convert to lambda expression

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8

I can configure Eclipse's code "Clean Up" to convert existing code expressions to lamba expressions if possible.

[image]

I am trying to find a way to manually trigger this, if possible only for the selected subset of my type.

I do not want to run the complete code cleanup, only the conversion to lambda expressions, and, if possible, also not for the complete type, but only for the selected part of it.

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is. 'Source > Clean Up....' runs the clean up on the selected files.

Comment: thanks for contributing, greg, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clean-ups are intended for mass operations. Since you don't seem to be interested in mass operation, you could consider using quick assist (`Ctrl+1`) on individual expressions.

**EDIT**: The quick assist is available since Eclipse Luna, see http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fjdt_whatsnew.html - second entry "Migrate anonymous class creations to lambda expressions and back".

Or: run the cleanup on a given file and the use the compare editor (against latest from git or similar) to only accept some selected changes.

Comment: True, I am not looking for a mass operation, nevertheless, I would like to use the lambda conversion from time to time.
Quick assist does not offer a conversion to lambda expression.

Comment: @kerner1000 do you still have trouble invoking the quick assist (see the EDIT in my answer)?

Comment: @Herrmann I didnt try it myself, since I am still on Mars. But quick assist seems to be what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @kerner1000, Eclipse Mars (4.5) is the successor of Luna (4.4), and Luna is the release in which these quick assists were first published, so you should be able to use them. Please see the explanation in the linked "What's New".

Comment: @Herrmann ups, you are right ;) But Strg+1 shows only "no suggestions available".